# want to add background image using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add background image using css but nothing is displaying in the browser

```css
.right-flex{
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #deeaee;
    padding: 1em 0;
    background-image: url("images/christmas-is-coming-christmas-wreath.gif");
}
```

```html
<div class="right-flex">
    <p>Display Image</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When replacing `images/christmas-is-coming-christmas-wreath.gif` with a reference to another similar GIF available on the Internet, it's displayed without issue. Can you verify if you're seeing any issues around `404 Not Found` errors relating to the relative reference of this image file? Otherwise, there may be additional context that you haven't provided here. At the moment, it looks like this is not reproducible.

Comment: did you set the image height and width? Make sure the file path is correct. Try to see if other image formats work (e.g. PNG, JPG etc).

Comment: The div isn't very tall so it's just possible,assuming you've got the path to the image correct, that almost none of it is showing.

Comment: There is No such thing when i searched the url

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code (using my own local gif file for testing), it works fine across Chrome, Edge, Firefox and IE.

Just taking a wild guess, is your image folder stored in a different directory? If the image folder is stored under a relative file path, you can try below code (in this case, image folder is one level above):

```
background-image: url("../images/christmas-is-coming-christmas-wreath.gif");
```

If you got your gif file from a website, pasting the image link from the website directly into `background-image: url()` also works.